# How to disable dates after current date in javascript calender

Tags: javascript, calendar, datepicker

I want to disable the dates after the current date in my program.

I have a date picker written in JavaScript.

My JavaScript code:

[Click here to view my JavaScript code.](http://csmagik.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-disbale-dates-after-current-date.html) 
Please help me in making necessary changes so as to disable the future date, i.e dates up to current date are only to be displayed.

Comment: Please post the relevant sections of code here so that they can be documented with the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it too late to switch to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)? The [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) provides this functionality easily:

```
$(function() {
   $('#datepicker').datepicker({ maxDate: 0 });
});
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max